# How to read cookie from response headers in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, express, nodes

I set cookie in my node server using :

```
res.cookie('userValidation','true',{httpOnly: false, secure: false });
```

I want to access this cookie in angular js : 
[image]

How to access this cookie in angular js?
I tried may time but i failed to read this. Anyone can give me a good way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [$cookies](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies) to access this data and **ensure** that your cookie **is not set as** [HttpOnly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#HttpOnly_cookie). Note that: **You can't access them directly e.g by using `header('Set-Cookie');`.**

#### Include your ressources:

```
<script src="angular.js"></script>
<script src="angular-cookies.js"></script>
```

#### Write your application:

```
var myApp = angular.module('app',['ngCookies']); 

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',  function($scope, $http , $cookies, $timeout){

  $scope.request = function(){
    $http.get('/api-end-point').then(function(response){
      $timeout(function(){
        console.log($cookies.userValidation)
      });         
    })
  }
})
```

Comment: console.log($cookies.userValidation) returning undefined.

Comment: @abhimanyu could you try to updated my answer. What have you done to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this ?

```
$http.get('/some').success(function(data, status, header) {
  console.log(header('cookie');
});
```

OR

```
$cookies = $browser.cookies();
```

Comment: @DeparPatidar Did you tried this? Should be good to validate an answer before posting instead let the user try it first.

Comment: @lin Yes my bad.

Comment: console.log(header('cookie') is returning null.